# How to merge two dataframes with overlapping columns, update existing values and add new values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I would like to merge two dataframes and update values in the first dataframe from the second dataframe.

I need to add all values from `data2` to `data1` and if the `username` already exists in `data1` I need the `amount` value to be updated from `data2`.

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = pd.DataFrame([['user1',  10], ['user2', 11], ['user3',  12],['user4',10]], columns=['username', 'amount'])
data2 = pd.DataFrame([['user4', 15], ['user5', 60]], columns=['username', 'amount'])
#Desired dataframe:  
data3= pd.DataFrame([['user1',  10], ['user2', 11], ['user3',  12],['user4',15], ['user5', 60]],columns=['username', 'amount'])
```

I would like to update vaues existing in both dataframes and add new rows if they are not in the first dataframe:

```
Dataframes:
data1:
username    amount
0   user1   10
1   user2   11
2   user3   12
3   user4   10

data2:
username    amount
0   user4   15
1   user5   60

data3: (Desired dataframe)
username    amount
0   user1   10
1   user2   11
2   user3   12
3   user4   15
4   user5   60
```

I tried Concat, Merge, Update, Join but couldn't get them to work in the way I want.

**Concat**:

```
print('Concat:')
df_concat = pd.concat([data1, data2], axis=0, join='outer', ignore_index='true', verify_integrity='True')
display(df_concat)


username    amount
0   user1   10
1   user2   11
2   user3   12
3   user4   10
4   user4   15
5   user5   60
```

**Merge:**

```
print('Merge:')
df_merge = data1.merge(data2,how='outer', on='username',indicator = True) 
display(df_merge)

username    amount_x    amount_y    _merge
0   user1   10.0    NaN left_only
1   user2   11.0    NaN left_only
2   user3   12.0    NaN left_only
3   user4   10.0    15.0    both
4   user5   NaN 60.0    right_only
```

**Update:**

```
print('Update:')
data1.update(data2)
display(data1)

    username    amount
0   user4   15.0
1   user5   60.0
2   user3   12.0
3   user4   10.0
```

**Join:**

```
print('Join:')
data1.join(data2, how='outer', lsuffix='username', rsuffix='amount')
display(data1)

username    amount
0   user1   10
1   user2   11
2   user3   12
3   user4   10
```

How do I get the desired dataframe data3 from data1 and data2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) + [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
data3 = pd.concat([data1, data2]).drop_duplicates(subset=["username"], keep="last")

print(data3)
```

**Output**

```
  username  amount
0    user1      10
1    user2      11
2    user3      12
0    user4      15
1    user5      60
```